# Can Dojo dGrid or GridX be used with a standard HTML table and not rewrite the table code

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dojo.gridx

I am working on application that requires Dojo grids to be used but I want to write the HTML for the table layout myself and use Dojo to insert the store data.

Is there a way with either dGrid or GridX to accomplish this, or is there a way to dynamically build tables/grids using the Dojo store?

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking if dgrid or gridx can literally just shove data into an existing table element in-place, the answer is no.  You could do that directly with a dojo/store by calling the `query` method and adding a row for each result.

Here's the general idea:

```
var columnFields = [...];
store.query().forEach(function (item) {
    var row = domConstruct.create('tr');
    for (var i = 0, len = columnFields.length; i < len; i++) {
        var cell = domConstruct.create('td', {}, row);
        // Add the field value to a text node rather than setting as innerHTML
        // to avoid unwanted tag injection
        cell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(item[columnFields[i]));
    }
    tbody.appendChild(row);
});
```

The closest you can get to this idea with dgrid is [dgrid/GridFromHtml](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.16/doc/components/core-components/GridFromHtml.md), which will let you define the grid's structure using a table with thead and header cells.  Combine that with [OnDemandGrid](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.16/doc/components/core-components/OnDemandList-and-OnDemandGrid.md) or [Pagination](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v0.3.16/doc/components/extensions/Pagination.md) for store support.

As far as I know, gridx does not have something similar to this at all.